# Regex for string with html tags

Tags: html, regex

I would like to make a regex to find all words that are separates with a space without separate html tags that contains spaces like `<span style="color:#FF0000;">`

I have made this regex:
/([^\s]+)/

But the result is incomplete because its separate the html in a sentence like this:

```
bonjour et bienvenue dan<span style="color:#FF0000;"><u><i><b>s ce tutoriel où nous allons</b></i></u></span> <span style="color:#FF0000;">apprendre </span>ici à faire une somme sur Excel donc tout d'abord nous allons voir Axel
```

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Use an XML parser. This will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: Ok. The main goal of this is to add a new tag inside each space between words. So, what is the best way to do this with an xml parser ?

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the tags with string.replace using the regex below. If you want the individual words you could then split the resulting string on spaces. This assumes you're using javascript, but you could easily adapt this to any language with regex support.

```js
var string = "bonjour et bienvenue dan<span style=\"color:#FF0000;\"><u><i><b>s ce tutoriel où nous allons</b></i></u></span> <span style=\"color:#FF0000;\">apprendre </span>ici à faire une somme sur Excel donc tout d'abord nous allons voir Axel";

var tagsStripped = string.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,'');

alert(tagsStripped);

alert(tagsStripped.split(' '));
```